# Setting foreground color for HSSFCellStyle is always coming out black

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I am using POI to create an Excel spreadsheet in Java. I have the following code used for creating a header row:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Report");

// some more code

HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();

cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);

cellStyle.setFont(font);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

The issue I am having is that setting the fill background color on the cell always comes out black, no matter what color I pick. What am I doing wrong? If I don't use the "setFillPattern" line, no color shows up at all.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I got this to work. I had to set the foreground color to make the background color work (??).

So I changed:

```
cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
```

to:

```
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
```

and it worked!

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  I need change the foreground color to change the background color - genius!

Comment: I think the cell is painted with a pattern that consists of foreground and background pixels. If you use SOLID_FOREGROUND, just the foreground pixel are visible. This color is different from the color used to render text, which is set with the font.

Comment: Thx Axel !!

Note : the Javadoc of the 2 implementations is very clear about this,

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillBackgroundColor(short)

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setFillBackgroundColor(short)

Saddly, the base class does not says a word about that
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillBackgroundColor(short)

Comment: With Apache POI version > 4 you now have to use the following : `HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex()`.

Answer (score 13):

If you are setting the foreground color, use

```
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

If you are setting the background color, use

```
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.THICK_BACKWARD_DIAG);
```

or

```
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.THIN_BACKWARD_DIAG);
```

The foreground and background colors seem to 'stack' (red + blue = purple)  if you set the foreground fill pattern before the background fill pattern, but not the other way round. There are several other fill patterns you can choose from. Note that the color will not be applied if you do not change the default fill pattern.

`CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND` is deprecated in version 3.15+. Use `FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND` instead.

Comment: A good explanation about `style.setFillForegroundColor( IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex() );
   style.setFillPattern( FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND );` which helped me, Thanks +1 ):-

Answer (score 1):

csHeader.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.SKY_BLUE.index);
csHeader.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);