# apache poi - CellStyle color cell

Tags: apache-poi, export-to-excel

After searching i found a solution on stackoverflow:

Refering to this
[Setting foreground color for HSSFCellStyle is always coming out black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803841/setting-foreground-color-for-hssfcellstyle-is-always-coming-out-black)

```
csFirstRow.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
csFirstRow.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

But it seems to have no effect.

Reading and searching google / Poi Docs desnt help.

How to Colorize a Cell using apache Poi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be unnessecary to set the Fill Background. It requires the "fillPattern"

```
csFirstRow.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
csFirstRow.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

> ### as javadoc says (setFillPattern)
>
> setting to one fills the cell with the foreground color... No idea about other values

Now it works as it should

thanks to this [helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530150/1221807) answer on stackoverflow