# Apache POI Excel row color is only black and doesn't change

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to make excel files background one row white and other aqua color. But for some reason whatever I do the color always changes to black.

```
private void writeTable(Table table, Row row, CellStyle style){
    if(row.getRowNum() % 2 == 0) {
        style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.AQUA.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    }
    style.setWrapText(true);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(table.index);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);

    //And it continues with other cells
}
```

It doesn't change whatever I do, even if I try GREY_25_PERCENT its completely black.
[Here's picture of my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsQon.png)

Comment: samet can you send your code

Comment: @java.nazif StackOverflow is based on the English language. Please do not use anything else.

Comment: Are you mistakenly re-using the same style every time?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens thank you I rushed into :)

Comment: @Gagravarr sadly no. I deleted all styles and created a new style but still had the same problem. Can there be a problem that Excel is fixed to Black & White colors or something?

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu I know it looks weird, but try using `setFillForegroundColor()` instead of `setFillBackgroundColor()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting foreground color for HSSFCellStyle is always coming out black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803841/setting-foreground-color-for-hssfcellstyle-is-always-coming-out-black)

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens I love you man:D if you post that as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may seem counterintuitive, but using

```
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

in combination with

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.AQUA.getIndex());
```

sets the background color of a cell.

The cell background itself probably also consists of two layers: a foreground and a background.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

instead of

```
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

It works with Apache POI 4.1.1